# Help to make fully adjustable paper stack in Blender 3.1 (from Blender 2.93)

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, geometry-nodes

A complete beginner here trying to recreate some projects to learn by experience.

I was following blender 2.93 tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dc2Mt0AK-qA&list=PLbHww4s6zG1UZ5-wwtyp-IhZLzY1X2tSr&index=11 ) on how to create a fully adjustable paper (money) stack

- Number of papers in stack
- Random Rotation
- Random Position

Here is the result I had in blender 2.93 but how to recreate same with new node system in blender 3.1?

[image]

Here is the node structure from old nodes. I tried every reddit post to understand what to do but i REALLY can't get my head around it. Please give me some pointers how to recreate same thing here...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was too lazy to name the inputs correctly but i think it is not too hard to find out ;)

[image]

[image]

with random positions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chris. God bless you man... If you are ever in Prague holler I will repay this in kind

Comment: Please click on the checkmark left to my answer if this helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Chris I am losing my texture image i have on it is there a way to keep it?

Comment: if you provide your blend file, i will check it. it depends how you did it...

Comment: Here you go bro: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19iYdSJtdj9gMYZa1S0H0iM0n7XjWelmv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JunaPaichadze: you didn't add the material to your circle object. so select circle, go on material properties, press +, then select the material you want to have [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CglcI.png

Comment: but please - do not ask further questions in comments. Just open a new question so everybody can learn from it. Thanks. You can ask/open as many questions as you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134905/discussion-between-juna-paichadze-and-chris).